# Differences between Doc comments and Comments in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, comments

May be it seems simple but I'm interested about knowing the exact differences between Doc Comments and Comments in Dart.

**///** this is a **Doc Comment**

**//** this is a **Comment**

In my view, Asking and Answering here can be helpful for others too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comments (//)**

Comments usually used to comment out some part of your code or adding some comments in your code, which you want to communicate with your team-mates.

**Doc Comments (///)**

Doc comment is for documentation purpose. The dartdoc parses doc comments and creates documentation pages.

```
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Comments                                   | Doc Comments                                        |
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  - Comment out some part of your code      | - Anything that you want to document using dartdoc  |
|  - Private APIs                            | - Usually used for public API/Framework/Library     |
|  - Private variable declaration            |                                                     |
|  - Method implementation logic             |                                                     |
|  - Something you need to do in future      |                                                     |
|    for improvements or cleanup purpose etc |                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

You can read more about these in [Effective Dart - Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation)